# Removing root node in Json with multiple values

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json data stored in a variable.

Json Data:

```
var employees = {"emp":{{"firstName":"John"},{"secondName":"John"}}};
```

From above JSON Data, I should not have emp node. I need JSON Data as

```
{{"firstName":"John"},{"secondName":"John"}};
```

How can i remove using Javascript.

Comment: Your JSON is not syntactically correct. Run this in your browser's console to see the errors

Comment: You should verify the `json` data in http://jsonlint.com/.

Answer (score 3):

if your `employee` object is

```
var employees = {"emp":{"firstName":"John","secondName":"John"}}; //since your original object is not correct
```

simply do

```
employees = employees.emp;
```

Comment: No My object is of form. 
{"emp":{{"firstName":"John"},{"secondName":"John"}}};

Comment: @MajidHussain didn't get you.

Comment: As my object is of form
{"emp":{{"firstName":"John"},{"secondName":"John"}}};
This one doesn't work

Comment: @MajidHussain this syntax is wrong. Are you able to run this object code standalone in an isolated simple app?

Comment: Yes. This is a situation like a element key having multiple values. Like an array

Comment: @MajidHussain in that case it should be `{"emp":[{"firstName":"John"},{"secondName":"John"}]};`